# PIC16F676 interacting with FT232 hookup

Tags: microcontroller, pic, usb, cmos, ftdi

I am hooking up a PIC16F676 to FT232. I already have power hooked and also OSC with 20 MHz and 22pF capacitor.

I am still trying to figure out the proper way to hook up the data/serial or something to program this chip using the FTDI FT232RL.

This is what I have so far:
[image: FTDI PIC hook]

And my datasheets:

PIC- http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/40039f.pdf

FTDI- https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232R.pdf

Overall, I just need to know if it's possible to hook FTDI to PIC16F676 in order to program. If so, then please guide me and once it's done, then I'll try to use c# application to program it (basically a custom tool).

Comment: You won't be able to program this chip via serial, at least, initially. You'd have to use proprietary programming tools like Pickit.

Comment: https://www.franksteinberg.de/FT232-PIC-Programmer.htm

Comment: 20mHz seems a bit slow. You sure it isn't 20MHz?

Comment: 20mHz is a default operating speed where it says in pg 2 at PDF, so that oscillator you see there is 20 mHz. I thought that there was at least some possibilities to program PIC with FTDI since I kind of want to be more of a DIY guy. But at this case, it may be difficult to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to program the PIC via a UART interface you need a bootloader.
But at least you need a programming tool for your PIC (e.g. MPLAB Snap) to programm the bootloader into your blank controller. Afterwards you can program the controller via UART.

Comment: Thanks for response. I am currently ordering the PIC Kit, then, when I get it, I'll look into its functionality and try to clone it by forming a circuit, see if it's possible.

Comment: You are welcome. Maybe have a look at MPLAB Snap.

Comment: Just got the PIC Kit 3, learned to work with it, everything works fine.